# Calling Methods of Structs in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, methods, struct, call

When coding in Swift, if I call a method of a struct and the method has only one parameter do I need to state the label of the parameter or only the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on your implementation.

#### Implementation 1:

If your implementation is something like this:

```
func myMethod(myParam: String) -> String
{
    return "Midhun is \(myParam)"
}
```

You can call the method like:

```
yourObj.myMethod("good");
```

---

#### Implementation 2

If your implementation have explicit argument name, like:

```
func myMethod(character myParam: String) -> String
{
    return "Midhun is \(myParam)"
}
```

You need to call it using:

```
yourObj.myMethod(character: "good");
```